# Ophthalmic usage in Great Expectations

Tags: meaning, literature, books

In chapter 10 of Great Expectations by Charles Dickens, it says:

> Yet I do not call to mind that I was ever in my earlier youth the subject of remark in our social family circle, but some large-handed person took some such **ophthalmic** steps to patronize me.

I searched up the word "ophthalmic" and I got "of or relating to the eye and its diseases." What does this mean in the sentence?

Comment: I think this should be General Reference to anyone who'd just read the sentence two before the one cited (and it's utterly meaningless to anyone who *hasn't*).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word refers to what the narrator says two sentences earlier:

> And here I may remark that when Mr. Wopsle referred to me, he considered it a necessary part of such reference to rumple my hair and **poke it into my eyes**. I cannot conceive why everybody of his standing who visited at our house should always have put me through the same inflammatory process under similar circumstances. Yet I do not call to mind that I was ever in my earlier youth the subject of remark in our social family circle, but some large-handed person took some such ophthalmic steps to patronize me.

Pip expresses his distaste for having his hair rubbed in his eyes by referring to it ironically with the medical term, as if Mr. Wopsle and others were graciously treating him for a disease rather than perpetrating a gratuitous indignity.